# VCL Register Properties in Category not working

Tags: delphi, components, vcl

I am trying to group some properties of my component.

```
type
  TcxGridButton = class(TcxButton)
  private
    FGridView : TcxGridDBTableView;
    FPopup : TPopupMenu;
    FImages : TcxImageList;
    FSortFilterEnabled : boolean;
    FCustomizeAndGroupEnabled : boolean;

    procedure AutoSize(Sender : TObject);
    procedure ClearFilter(Sender : TObject);
    procedure ExportToExcel(Sender : TObject);

    procedure SortFilter(Sender : TObject);
    procedure CustomizeAndGroup(Sender : TObject);

    procedure OnPopup(Sender : TObject);
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent); override;

    procedure Click; override;
  published
    property GridView : TcxGridDBTableView read FGridView write FGridView;
    property AllowSortFilter : boolean read FSortFilterEnabled write FSortFilterEnabled;
    property AllowCustomizeAndGroup : boolean read FCustomizeAndGroupEnabled write FCustomizeAndGroupEnabled;
  end;
```

I wish to show AllowSortFilter and AllowCustomizeAndGroup in VCL under a Group named PopupMenu Settings.

So I did this :

```
procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Roberts', [TcxGridButton]);

  RegisterPropertiesInCategory('PopupMenu Settings', TcxGridButton, ['AllowSortFilter','AllowCustomizeAndGroup']);
end;
```

Unfortunately this is not working, and I have no idea why. The Syntax seems to be correct get no errors . But the Group is not being created.

Regards
Robert

Comment: Dear God ... how do you describe not working with other words ? :)
It is not Registering the two Properties under the Category ...

Comment: With respect, you wrote "not working", not "not registering".  What behaviour of the ide makes you think that the properties are not being registered?

Comment: the Properties are Registered... but not under the Category named Popupmenu Settings...
This line has no effect , so it seems : 
RegisterPropertiesInCategory('PopupMenu Settings', TcxGridButton, ['AllowSortFilter','AllowCustomizeAndGroup']);

Comment: Also what find strange I can compile and install the Component, but when I put the component on a form and try to compile it complains about designintf not found...

Comment: The "designintf not found" is because you are trying to compile design-time code into your application - you need to put your code to register your component into a separate unit and **not** have that in your app's Uses list.

Comment: thank you , that one I somehow overlooked

Comment: Btw, you might take a look at https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=9JzBn4vcUBoC&pg=PA538&lpg=PA538&dq=delphi+RegisterPropertiesInCategory&source=bl&ots=wATnRznqsZ&sig=ACfU3U0TbeBi-4AEwdtsLsoEUBLvnluvdg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiT1Pe91srjAhVcVBUIHVCMDp4Q6AEwA3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=delphi%20RegisterPropertiesInCategory&f=false; it's quite old but still relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are possibly missing a step somewhere, because if I organise your
code as I think it should be organised, then I get the result that the
`AllowSortFilter` and `AllowCustomizeAndGroup` entries correctly show
up in the PopUpMenuSettings category of the cxGridButton.

Here's what I did:

- Placed your `TcxGridButton` code, but not your `Register` procedure in a new unit,
  CategoryRTu  (RT short for run-time).  This unit does **not** Use DesignIntf.
- Placed your `Register` procedure in a new unit CategoryDTu (DT short for DesignTime).  This unit **does** use DesignIntf.
- Created a new package, Category.Dpk, which `Contains` CategoryDTu and `Requires`
  rtl, designide, vcl, dbrtl, vcldb, dxGDIPlusD7, dxCoreD7, cxLibraryD7, dxThemeD7,
  cxPageControlD7, cxEditorsD7, cxDataD7, dxLayoutControlD7 and cxGridD7.  The D7
  suffixes are because I did this in Delphi7.  Some of these might not be strictly necessary, because I created the list by adding a TcxButton to a form and then
  copied some of the Used units into the `Requires` list.
- Compiled Category.Dpk and used `Component | Install packages` to install Category.Bpl.
- Created a new project and added a TcxGrid and a TcxGridButton to it.
- Selected cxGridButton1 in the Object Inspector, right-clicked in the OI
  and selected View | By Category

And then, expanding the PopUpMenuSettings node, I see `AllowSortFilter` and
`AllowCustomizeAndGroup`.

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed example. I am new at this as is seen :)